# PHP if statement fails to validate on "!== 0"

Tags: php, if-statement, equality

How can the below be possible:

```
$varnum = 4;
if( $varnum/4 - floor($varnum/4) !== 0){
    echo 'foo';
}
```

This echoes 'foo' on my server running PHP 5.1.6. If i change the operator to `==` I get the same results.

I have no idea why, but could it possibly be because "==" is "equals" and "!==" is "Not identical"? How then would I make them identical? I guess in javaScript I would "parseInt", but there is no such thing in PHP, right?

Comment: `!==` complements `===`, `!=` complements `==`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: in php, you absolutely must familiarize yourself with the var_dump() function to aid your debugging. then you can see why two things aren't equal.

Comment: @Jan Dovak, Of course! I feel so silly now. Thanks for the answer! Works like a charm!!

Comment: PHP, the only language where `0 !== 0.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this fails is because in PHP, the `floor` function returns a `float`, despite the fact that the value is always a whole number. You can see this in the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

You're doing a fixed type comparison of that float to an integer zero, so the result is false, regardless of whether the value is actually zero.

To fix this, either:

- cast the output of `floor` to an integer - either `intval(float(...))` or `(int)float(..)`
- use `!=` instead of `!==`.
- use `0.0` instead of just `0` to compare against.

In case you're wondering why `floor()` would return a float rather than an integer, it's because the input is a float. The float data type has a larger possible range than integer, and thus it is possible to call `floor()` on a value that would be too big to hold in an integer. Therefore it would not be safe for the function to return an integer; it returns a float instead so that it can guarantee the result will be correct.

It may seem odd at first glance, but hopefully that explains the logic behind it for you.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'll accept it when the system lets me, in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

What is it you are trying to accomplish?  If you are trying to see if $varnum is divisible by four then use modulus, so...

```
$varnum = 4;
if ($varnum % 4 != 0) {
    echo "foo - $varnum is divisible by 4";
}
```

You original post should use '!=' versus '!==', like this:

```
$varnum = 4;
if( $varnum/4 - floor($varnum/4) != 0){
    echo 'foo';
}
```